# Three Dimensional Lookup Using INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**This was taken and improved slightly from Question that has since been deleted**

For those who can see deleted posts, it was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793322/three-dimensional-lookup-no-concatenate-or-named-ranges-excel

---

I'm trying to do a three dimensional lookup without named ranges or concatenates. Simplified, my data is on the form:

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3
Scott           
P   1       2       3
M   4       5       6
N   7       8       9
George          
P   10      11      12
M   13      14      15
N   16      17      18
```

I now want to search for a specific Name and then for a specific letter within that names table, I then want to match this row number with a specific column.

I tried a simple INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH("M",A:A,0),MATCH("Column1",1:1,0))
```

And that works for the fist name but not any others as it finds the first instance of `M`.

How do I modify it to look for a different name?

---

I have answered below, but want to see if someone has a better solution.

Comment: it depends on the data input possibilities. If P, M, N are not always the letters(maybe more etc). Also are blanks only appearing on the lines with names?

Comment: As you can see from the current answer those assumptions have been made.  My answer assumes that it can be in any order.  The only caveat to mine is the size of the data set which is 4.  That would need to change to the largest dataset to minimize the false positives.  I am looking if we can do it without any caveats.  All the current answers have some sort of restriction. @MacroMarc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used an `IF()` statement `array` formula to find what the `P` row number was after the `George` row... I also needed to use the `MIN()` function to get the first `P` row number after the name.

Beyond that, it's a simple `INDEX()` function.... that racked my brain for over an hour :).

`=INDEX($A$1:$D$9,MIN(IF((ROW(A1:A9)>MATCH($F$4,A1:A9,0))*(A1:A9=$F$5),ROW(A1:A9),"")),MATCH($F$6,$A$1:$D$1,0))`

**Don't Forget!**
Use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when finishing the formula, so it gets evaluated as an `array` formula.

[image: 3 Dimensional Array Function]

Answer (score 16):

You can use two other INDEX/MATCH's inside the first MATCH to set the lookup range.  Then you simply need to add the MATCH() to find the absolute position of the name.

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH($H$4,INDEX(A:A,MATCH($H$3,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($H$3,A:A,0)+4),0)+MATCH($H$3,A:A,0)-1,MATCH($H$5,$1:$1,0))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

This one works better and does not have a size constraint:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(F4,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)):A1040000,0)+MATCH(F3,A:A,0)-1,MATCH(F5,A1:D1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this just by adding the results of two matches together. One match for the names plus one match for the letter equals the total row.

=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(G5,A3:A5,0)+MATCH(G3,A:A,0),MATCH(G4,1:1,0))

In other words: Index(All of the Data, Match(Name, In name column, exact) + Match(Letter, In letter column, exact), Match(Column name, in Column row, exact)

[Screen capture of working sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siUrw.png)

Comment: Simple and very good if the letters appear in that strict consistency after each name. Probably the best idea for the strictly consistent case.  But in the comments to the question, Scott Craner is trying to find formula constructions for a more general case, with the minimum amount of caveats or assumptions about the data input. Obviously there have to be some structure to the dataset, but I think that we shouldnt restrict it to being the same exact four letters in the same exact order.

Answer (score 4):

My answer attempts the general case with only one caveat:

**That a letter is single character text, and a name is more than 1 character.** Otherwise i feel there is no difference logically between letters and names, and it is then impossible to really do...

***RE-EDIT for better function construction:***

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$D$17, MATCH($H$3,$A1:$A17, 0)+MATCH($H$4, INDEX($A1:$A17, MATCH($H$3,$A1:$A17, 0)):INDEX($A:$A, SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH($H$3,$A1:$A17, 0)+POWER(SQRT(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$17)>1, ROW($A$1:$A$17), 0)-MATCH($H$3,$A$1:$A$17, 0)), 2)-1, ROWS($A$1:$A$17)), 2)), 0)-1, MATCH($H$5, $A$1:$D$1, 0))}
```

This uses an array formula along column A, and checks if the length is > 1 and throws the row nums into an array, with letters given a 0.

Then match row of unique name(e.g. George) is subtracted from each.

We then use a min(of all other name rows, with the last data row as the final default - SMALL function with 2 parameter) to find the next name row(or last data row if there is no following name).

Rest is standard index/match etc.

**It will correctly return #N/A if there is no such letter under the chosen name...**

[image]

My dataset is A1:A17, and the formula could use A:A instead each time, but the array calc inside the IF needs the A1:A17 for speed.

***EDIT for better function construction:***

If we wanted to avoid editing the formula when the data length changes, then we could let full column references of A:A go through the entire construction(and lose speed/efficiency) with the last data row in colA calculated via ROWS(A:A):

**Re-edit:**

```
{=INDEX($A:$D, MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)+MATCH($H$4, INDEX($A:$A, MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)):INDEX($A:$A, SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)+POWER(SQRT(IF(LEN($A:$A)>1, ROW($A:$A), 0)-MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)), 2)-1, ROWS($A:$A)), 2)), 0)-1, MATCH($H$5,1:1, 0))}
```

It really depends on the setup...

***Edit again for version which takes blanks as separators for names***

If you want to use blanks as the separator for names, where no blanks are in the data results, but blanks appear in columns B to D where there is a name, then a tiny change in the above formulae will result in this:

`=INDEX($A$1:$D$17, MATCH($H$3,$A$1:$A$17, 0)+MATCH($H$4, INDEX($A:$A, MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)):INDEX($A:$A, SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH($H$3,$A:$A, 0)+POWER(SQRT(IF($B$1:$B$17="", ROW($A$1:$A$17), 0)-MATCH($H$3,$A$1:$A$17, 0)), 2)-1, ROWS($A$1:$A$17)), 2)), 0)-1, MATCH($H$5, $A$1:$D$1, 0))`

This means that the names and letters do not have to be any specified length, but just one proviso is that blanks appear in the row with the name.

A small amendment to the condition to find the end range to search for the letter by replacing this: `SQRT(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$17)>1,` with this:

`SQRT(IF($B$1:$B$17="",`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the area (4th parameter) of Index(). Below is a screenshot of test data. This example assumes the same columns and keys are sorted and consistent.

This works by using (Range1,Range2) as the first parameter of index. For the 4th parameter of index, use N for which area in the () you want Index to return.

[image]

Comment: This is a good option if the area is known and there are few areas.  My guess is that there will be multiple names so adding areas for each name and counting the areas to get the correct one may get tedious, and a long formula.

Comment: Named ranges can help yet they only go so far. Plus, we have to remember the practicality of everything falling in line in the real world (we can dream?).

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be slightly tidier, and a little easier to modify maybe.

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($H$3,$A:$A,0),TRUE),0,0,4,4),MATCH($H$4,$A:$A,0),MATCH(H5,$1:$1,0))
```

Using offset to create the range first, we're able to use the name from H3 to set that up, and then beyond that we are just indexing within that new range.

Now this is still dependendent on staying in Column A for the names.

Comment: Yes but I tend to stay away from OFFSET and INDIRECT as it is a volatile function. In this instance where it is only one it is not a big deal but a page full of volatile functions will slow the Calculation times down.

Comment: Also as the first name is in row 2 not row one you need to make an adjustment to your first match of -1 or it will bring up the wrong number. `=INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($H$3,$A:$A,0),TRUE),0,0,4,4),MATCH($H$4,$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH(H5,$1:$1,0))`

Comment: Tidier and easier to modify ... perhaps, but you are also involving volatile functions.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Is there a list of volatile functions somewhere I could reference, or a rule of thumb for remembering which ones are volatile?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the format of the data is always `Name` then `P`, `M` and `N` this formula does the work:

```
=INDEX($A:$D,
MATCH($H$3,$A:$A,0)
+LOOKUP($H$4,{"P",1;"M",2;"N",3}),
MATCH($H$5,$1:$1,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution works on almost all conditions. One restriction I found is when one of the subjects *(Names)* does no have data for any of the details (letters), but as of now the same occurs with all the other answers.

The formula assumes the data is located at `B6:F30` (in order to ensure it can be applied regardless of the source range location).

The formula uses the Index\Match functions:

First, a MATCH to retrieve the position of the `Name`:

```
MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0)
```

With that info it uses INDEX to build a range that is used to obtain the position of the `Detail` (letter) using a second MATCH Function:

```
+ MATCH($I8,INDEX($B$6:$B$30, 1 + MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0))
:INDEX($B$6:$B$30,ROWS($B$6:$B$30)),0),
```

Adding the results of the first and second MATCH functions obtains the position of the `Name``Detail` combination and uses it in an Index to the entire data. The position of the Data Column required is obtained with a Match:

```
INDEX($B$6:$F$30, 1st.MATCH + 2nd.MATCH,
MATCH(J$6,$B$6:$F$6,0))
```

With the results located at `G6:L30` enter this formula in `J8` then copy to `J8:L30`:

```
= INDEX( $B$6:$F$30,
MATCH( $H8, $B$6:$B$30, 0)
+MATCH( $I8, INDEX( $B$6:$B$30 , 1 + MATCH( $H8, $B$6:$B$30 ,0))
: INDEX( $B$6:$B$30, ROWS($B$6:$B$30) ),0),
MATCH( J$6, $B$6:$F$6, 0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Again this works only if all the Details are the same, yes the order does not matter but the actual details do.  For example Take out Detail 2 for George from the data set and suddenly J8 will pull row 16 instead.  It will return false positives.  Your formula is very much like mine, I limited it to only four rows in hope to limit the false positives.

Comment: "One restriction I found is when one of the subjects (Names) does no have data for any of the details (letters), **but as of now the same occurs with all the other answers**." - My answer correctly finds #N/A if a name doesnt have the letter(or any letters)

Comment: @ScottCraner that's is what it does not work when one of the subjects (Names) does no have data for any of the details (letters) means.

Comment: @ScottCraner This formula is not like the one you posted. To verify just insert one column before the data (i.e. columns `A`) in both cases and the formula you posted will produce inaccurate results, insert three and it generates `#REF!` while the formula in this answer will continue showing correct results (with the exception already explained).

Comment: @MacroMarc Sorry, I have to admit that your formula returns the Error, but unfortunately it only works on the condition that the details have all the same length (one in this case), which in real life it does not happen often. Also if you add a row above the data your formula gets inaccurate.

Comment: @EEM, Good catch - I mixed reference techniques of full column + limited range. The second option I gave still works for all that in any case although I had to re-edit. As for the assumptions about data input, it's open. Some situations have letter/code of a specific format that can be tested. Some are free, but we have no other constraints passed to us. It's an attempt to solve the most general case. We need to separate out names. Either blanks may do, but we don't know whether blanks or zeroes will be in the data set. I feel blanks may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works in all conditions discussed so far *(let me know of any condition that it does not work and I’ll try to cover it)*.
I’m posting this as a separated answer as the formulas applied in prior answer rightly apply to the conditions stated in them, as such they will be useful to users with those specific scenarios, so they don’t need to apply these long formulas.

This formula assumes the data is located at `B6:E30` *(in order to ensure it can be applied regardless of the source range location)*.

This formula uses the Index\Match functions and it’s a Formula Array.

*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

**Syntax:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DataRng,
MATCH(Value1,NamesRng,0)
+IFERROR(MATCH(Value2,INDEX(NamesRng,
1+MATCH(Value1,NamesRng,0))
:INDEX(NamesRng, IFERROR(MATCH(Value1,NamesRng,0)
+MATCH("#",IF((INDEX(Col1Rng,1+MATCH(Value1,NamesRng,0))
:INDEX(Col1Rng,ROWS(NamesRng)))="","#","!"),0),
ROWS(NamesRng))),0),NA()),MATCH(ValCol,DataHdr,0)),"")
```

**Arguments:**
*Assuming the data is located at B6:E30.*

`Value1`= `Name` to be found in Data, i.e. George, Scott, etc.

`Value2`= `Detail` to be found in Data, i.e. Detail1, Detalle2, etc.

`ValCol` = `Column` to be found in Data i.e. Column1, Column2, etc.

`DataRng`= `$B$6:$E$30`

`DataHdr`= `$B$6:$E$6`

`NamesRng`= `$B$6:$B$30`

`Col1Rng`= `$C$6:$C$30`

*1st MATCH*: Retrieves the position of the Name:

```
MATCH(Value1,NamesRng,0)
```

*2nd MATCH*: Retrieves the end position of the Name’s corresponding Details, which is determined by a blank value in column `C` or the end of the data range:

```
MATCH("#",IF((INDEX(Col1Rng, 1 + 1stMATCH)
:INDEX(Col1Rng,ROWS(NamesRng)))="","#","!"),0),
```

*Builds a Range (vRange)*: With the Names's Details using the 1st and 2nd match functions. If 2nd Match returns an error then it uses the last row of the Data range:

```
INDEX(NamesRng, 1 + 1stMATCH )
:INDEX(NamesRng, IFERROR( 1stMATCH + 2ndMATCH, ROWS(NamesRng)))
```

*3rd MATCH*: Retrieves the position of the `Detail` within the vRange. It returns `#NA` if the combination is not present.

```
IFERROR(MATCH(Value2, vRange,0), NA())
```

Adding the results of the 1st and 3rd match functions obtains the Row index of the `Name``Detail`combination or`#NA`if no found.
The Column index is obtained with a Match from the Header of the Data.
It then applying the INDEX function to the Data Range returns the value of the`Name\Detail\Column`combination.
If the`Name\Detail` combination is not found it returns blank.

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( DataRng, 1stMATCH + 3rdMATCH, MATCH(Column,DataHdr,0)),"")
```

With the results located at H6:L37 enter this Formula Array in J8 then copy to K8:L37 and to J9:L37:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX($B$6:$E$30,
MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0)
+IFERROR( MATCH($I8, INDEX($B$6:$B$30,
1+MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0))
:INDEX($B$6:$B$30, IFERROR(MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0)
+MATCH("#", IF((INDEX($C$6:$C$30,1+MATCH($H8,$B$6:$B$30,0))
:INDEX($C$6:$C$30,ROWS($B$6:$B$30)))="","#","!"),0),
ROWS($B$6:$B$30))),0),NA()),
MATCH(J$6,$B$6:$E$6,0)), "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow... So many solutions already.

I think a simpler solution could be using offset to get a more generic answer.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$9, MATCH($G$3,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($G$2,$A$1:$A$9,0),0,3,1),0)+MATCH($G$2,$A$1:$A$9,0), MATCH($G$4,$B$1:$D$1,0)+1)
```

The only variable to look for is 3 which is the number of M/N/P options present because that will affect the number of rows. Otherwise, the solution works fine in all possible scenarios and different orders.

Answer (score 0):

When I have more than two inpunts for a data search I prefer to have the data organized as shown in the figure, so that I can use a pivot table and get it to organize the data in rows and columns as I like.

Then I use `GETPIVOTDATA` to search for a value.

Cell `G9` contains this formula:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Value";$F$3;"Name";G15;"Letter";G16;"Column";G17)`

[image]

Comment: If one could rearrange the data, it would be simpler to just use a SUMIFS to get the number: `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G15,B:B,G16,C:C,G17)`  But the challenge was to do it without changing the data structure.