# Searching for text in excel, use an offset, and then a logical test, to output a string of text

Tags: vba, excel

The main goal of this is too search for "MRQ", once "MRQ" is found have the code do an offset down one row where it then tests if the product is > benchmark then output "over" Else output "Under"

Here is the code that I have so far but I am having trouble inputting the second if clause.

```
Sub FindMRQ()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim MRQ As Range
Dim Product As Range
Dim Benchmark As Range

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sh.UsedRange

        Set MRQ = .Cells.Find(What:="MRQ")
        If Not MRQ Is Nothing Then
            MRQ.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
            Do Until MRQ Is Nothing
                    ActiveCell.Value = "YAY!"
                Set MRQ = .FindNext(MRQ)
            Loop
        End If

        'If Product.Range > Benchmark.Range Then
        '"Outperformed" Else
        'If Product.Range < Benchmark.Range Then
        '"Underperformed"
        ' End If


    End With
    Set MRQ = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Example of the Data Set
[image]

Comment: is "HRQ" always in the same row?

Comment: So, in your data set, you want to **replace** `2` with `Under`?

Comment: if HRQ is always in the same row, then a simple HLOOKUP will work, no need for vba.

Comment: take a look here for possible formula answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to put your `If` block before your `Do Until` loop but after the selection of the cell you are wanting to check. Something like this:

```
Sub FindMRQ()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim MRQ As Range
    Dim Product As Range
    Dim Benchmark As Range

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sh.UsedRange

            Set MRQ = .Cells.Find(What:="MRQ")
            If Not MRQ Is Nothing Then
                MRQ.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0).Select
                If MRQ.Value > Benchmark.Value Then
                    MsgBox "Outperformed"
                ElseIf MRQ.Value < Benchmark.Value Then
                    MsgBox "Underperformed"
                End If
                Do Until MRQ Is Nothing
                        ActiveCell.Value = "YAY!"
                    Set MRQ = .FindNext(MRQ)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
        Set MRQ = Nothing
    Next Sh
End Sub
```

You will probably still need to tweak this to get it exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula instead of VBA:

```
=IF(HLOOKUP("MQR",$A$1:$D$4,MATCH("Product",$A$1:$A$4,0),0)>HLOOKUP("MQR",$A$1:$D$4,MATCH("Benchmark",$A$1:$A$4,0),0),"Outperformed","Underperformed")
```

[image]