# Excel: lookup multiple criteria but same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

here is a quick sample of the sheet:

[image]

How would I go about looking up multiple criteria? I want to look for the "candy" under "machine3" and return the value next column over ("1" in this case), or look for "cream" under "machine2".

I appreciate any tip on this.

Comment: Hmm, a tough one but I think I have an idea. Are the machines always in ascending order (1 > 2 > 3 etc.)

Comment: Do you want the search for "cream" under "machine2" to return the result from row 10, or an error/not found?

Comment: @jblood94 I hadn't even thought of that but it is unclear now that I have re-read it

Comment: see if any of these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Comment: Good point, "error" would be what I was thinking; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$14,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$14=E2,IF(ROW($A$1:$A$14)>MATCH("machine"&D2,$A$1:$A$14,0),IFERROR(IF(ROW($A$1:$A$14)<MATCH("machine"&D2+1,$A$1:$A$14,0),ROW($A$1:$A$14)),ROW($A$1:$A$14)))),1)),"Not Found")`

This is an array formula - use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

Looks for the match of the product, then evaluates the row against the `MATCH()` of the machine number and the machine number above it and returns the smallest result.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much...now to interpret your code! :)

Comment: @Dergyll Glad to help out. If you need me to explain the formula let me know and I'll do so at the end of my working day.

Answer (score 1):

See the image below. If by "under" you mean anywhere under, then use the formula in `E2`:

`=VLOOKUP(D3,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$14,0)+1&":B14"),2,FALSE)`

If by "under" you mean under the machine specified, but before the next machine, then use the formula in `F2` (which returns "Not found" if it is not found before the next machine):

```
=IF(MATCH(D3,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$14,0)+1&":A14"),0)<MATCH("machine*",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$14,0)+1&":A14"),0),VLOOKUP(D3,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$14,0)+1&":B14"),2,FALSE),"Not found")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer jblood94

Answer (score -1):

Write the below formula in B2 Cell and filldown

=IF(AND(A1="machine3", A2="candy"),1,IF(AND(A1="machine2", A2="cream"),1,""))

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't correctly answer the OP's question as it only looks at the cell directly below the `machine`