# INDEX MATCH with variable array

Tags: excel-formula

In the image below I want to do an INDEX MATCH lookup on column A in the 'Position' table and return the value in column C (Unhedged %).  I can't hard code the array to lookup because the relevant cell range is variable (i.e. the Position table may begin at row 5 or 9 or 13 etc) and is of variable length.  I can't do a lookup on the entire column because some values exist more than once.
   How can I define a variable array that begins after the 'Position' cell?  Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Answer (score 0):

The value associated with EUR in B:C within the Position group can be retrieved with,

```
'column B (local)
=INDEX(B:C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))="EUR")*(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))>MATCH("position", A:A, 0))), 1), 1)
'column C (unhedged)
=INDEX(B:C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))="EUR")*(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))>MATCH("position", A:A, 0))), 1), 2)
```