# lookup with indirect / reference

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, offset

I am struggeling the vlookup, offset, indirect functions on my workbook.

on my Import sheet i get thought the query my datas from several excel files
[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M55I9.png)

on my evaluation the C3 is dynamic through a dropdown from around 100 different names. some are import to sheet "import" ,some will be import  on another time.

D5:D8 should have a lookup according to the choosen name in Evaluation!C3

in addition i need in the Evaluation F:H area a sum from all "Names" datas together.

[evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkszy.png)

i tried several formulas like offset, indirect, match,..
even pivot and vba. i couldn't assemble the formula right.

someone know a way how i can solve that?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have more than one question here, it would be better to break things down and ask one question for each problem you want to solve. when you do, don't forget to include the formulas you have tried and explain what the result you expect is.

Comment: i tried in the Evaluation!D5 cell following formula: =OFFSET(VLOOKUP(Evaluation!C3,Import!A1:C999,2,FALSE),2,1)  i thought i can set the offset reference throught the vlookup, but it won´t work

Comment: See here for something close.  There are many answers, one is bound to help you do the lookup part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match