# How to find a row in excel based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image]

and I'm trying to find a formula to fill in cells E2 and E3.
If tried multiple combinations of LOOKUP(V and H),MATCH,ADDRESS and others but can't get the right result.
Does anyone have any ideas.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: missing the spreadsheet!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Answer (score 0):

In **E2** and **E3** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A3:B14,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(D1,A17:B28,2,FALSE)
```

This assumes that the dates are text values *(in both column **A** and cell **D1**)*:

[image]