# Advanced match with more than one critera

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to autofill a table from a source table. The solution needs to take into consideration two criterias. The first is a match on Column 1, top node ("One", "Two", etc) and the second is that it needs to match the sub-node in Column 1 ("AA", "BB" etc). Given a match, the corresponding value in Column 2 should be fetched. This value should be populated in an identical table in the destination. Hence the destination table is where we match the nodes to, and the result go into the yellow cells.

How do I do this double criteria solution?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Add a helper column to your original source and populate with the corresponding top node for each row. Then use SUMIFS.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three Dimensional Lookup Using INDEX/MATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match)