# Excel Sum if, critera range1 on a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Title says it all pretty much, So in the image the sum looks for the first entry as it has "mr human" in the cell next to it but when i try to designate my critera range for a single cell i get #value returned, I can solve this by entering "mr human" into all the adjacent cells however to sheet I am pulling the data from has is formatted like It is shown so it would be ideal If i didnt have to make a copy then do that as this can be for several hundred "mr & Ms/miss"

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: the best option is to add a helper column with a simple formula to create the normalized data set.  Then use that helper column as the criteria.

Comment: @ScottCraner would a sum sumif array or something not work? like =SUMIF(SUMIF(E3:E10,A2)(G:G,B4,F:F) ?

Comment: It is a fairly complicated formula to do what you want.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match  It is just too complicated when a simple formula in H2 , `=IF(E2<>"",E2,H1)` then copy down the data set.  Then you use H in your SUMIFS formula instead of E.

Comment: @ScottCraner ok awesome thanks for the example link! and got it, thats neat the little forumla there as well! thanks for the help scott, ill have a mess around and see what i can come back with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would say that you should indeed consider using a different model data for this, as suggested by @ScottCraner.

Second, this solution may work, but if you have a lot of sets (when i mean sets, i mean Mr Human, Miss Human, Kid Human, Grandp Human, and many more) it can be kind of annoying.

Now, first thing you must do is creating *named* ranges of each set of data. So the values related to *Mr Human* will be named`MR_HUMAN` and values of *Miss Human* will be named `MISS_HUMAN`. It's easy to do.

Remember:

1. Names can't have blanks, spaces, or any weird char. Just use underscore.
2. Each name must be unique
3. Each name must contain 2 columns: first one is Code and Second one Cost.

A video example (type the name and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Now the formula for column C:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3;CHOOSE(MATCH($A$3;{"Mr Human";"Miss Human"};0);MR_HUMAN;MISS_HUMAN);2;FALSE);"Not found")
```

You can see below that if I change cell A3 to Miss Human, values change properly:

[image]

This is how the formula works:

1. `MATCH($A$3;{"Mr Human";"Miss Human"};0)` This will search the text in `A3` into the array of sets and will return a number according to position. In this case, `Mr Human=1` and `Miss Human=2`
2. `CHOOSE(*number from step 1*;MR_HUMAN;MISS_HUMAN)` We use the number obtained in step 1 to combine with function CHOOSE, which allows to select a result based on a list. So we can use this function to relate number 1 to name `MR_HUMAN` and number 2 to `MISS_HUMAN` and it will return our target range with right values.
3. `VLOOKUP(B3;*name from step 2*;2;FALSE)` We combine the range from previous step and use it as matrix of a normal VLOOKUP, that will search the CODE in first column, and will return the value from second one (COST)
4. We trap all above inside an IFERROR, just to avoid VLOOKUP returning an error (error in VLOOKUP means that CODE is not found in that range).

The big issue here is that if you got a lot of datasets for more values, besides *Mr Human* and *Miss Human*, you need to adjust the MATCH and CHOOSE part, and can be annoying.

Anyways, hope this helps a little bit.

> [VLOOKUP
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
>
> [IFERROR
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)
>
> [MATCH
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
>
> [CHOOSE
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc)

Also, consider using a different data model and the resume data using Pivot Tables.

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much for all the detail included in the post, I really appreciate the help!, I have one final question with this how would it work of there were columns between my code and cost column? I cant seem to get it to work with that but I can just put those columns togeather but would be interested if its possible to get that to work too, thank you so much again

Comment: First column must be **always** the code. Cost column can be anywhere inside each named range. You just need to change the `2` inside VLOOKUP to the new position of your column (3,4,5...whatever). And ALL named ranges must have same number of columns too

Comment: ooooooooh awesome got it, thank you so much again! :D