# Excel sumif with both horizontal and vertical criteria's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, sumifs

I have the below table

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Posters | 1-10 | 11-50 | 51-100 | 101-200 |
| a | £ 0.41 | £ 0.41 | £ 0.37 | £ 0.32 |
| b | £ 0.83 | £ 0.82 | £ 0.73 | £ 0.64 |
| d | £ 24.37 | £ 16.67 | £ 13.52 | £ 10.12 |
| d | £ 0.50 | £ 0.50 | £ 0.44 | £ 0.39 |
| e | £ 1.00 | £ 0.99 | £ 0.89 | £ 0.78 |
| Others | 1-40 | 41-60 | 61-90 | 91-200 |
| de | £ 0.41 | £ 0.41 | £ 0.37 | £ 0.32 |
| fg | £ 0.83 | £ 0.82 | £ 0.73 | £ 0.64 |
| hi | £ 24.37 | £ 16.67 | £ 13.52 | £ 10.12 |
| jk | £ 0.50 | £ 0.50 | £ 0.44 | £ 0.39 |
| lm | £ 1.00 | £ 0.99 | £ 0.89 | £ 0.78 |

I have the above examples based on these two master tables I have another tab where I select the type of product such as using the above examples

Order Form

| Product | Type | Quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Poster | 10 | ?? |
| de | Others | 60 | ?? |

I want to basically use the cost field to work out the cost. So take the first row above as an example 'A' is within the 'Poster' table therefore I want the formula to identify this and use the weightings (1-10) to work out the cost.

What will be the best formula for this?

Comment: See if any of the answers here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDEX($B$2:$E$11,MATCH(A15,$A$2:$A$11,0),MATCH(C15,--LEFT(INDEX($B$1:$E$11,MATCH(B15,$A$1:$A$11,0),),FIND("-",INDEX($B$1:$E$11,MATCH(B15,$A$1:$A$11,0),))-1),1))*C15`

It looks for the matching row first. Then for the matching column it looks for the number value prior to the `-` in the row of either `Posters` / `Others`

[image]

PS it's easier if you would be able to limit the headers to the lowest value only. That way the formula would be much simpler.

I reckon `Posters` vs `Poster` was a typo and one of the Posters `d` should actually be `c`?